# HttpPost a file from Node js to .net Core C#

Tags: c#, node.js, post, .net-core, binding

I have been having no issues at all binding to HttpPost requests from node js using node-fetch, but I am hitting major snags when it comes to trying to send files.

I can bind to an object just fine if I have the type as Object, but then I obviously don't know what to cast it to in order to work with it.

I'm willing to try basically anything as long as it comes from Node and ends up in .net Core. If the file type is relevant, I am trying to send .7z files.

Comment: https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/how-to-upload-files-in-net-core-web-api-and-react-36a8fbf5c9e8

Comment: Where the nodejs code runs? In browser or on server?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I am not intimately familiar with the difference but I believe a browser? I am running it via a terminal.